# Position Feedback for Stepper Motor

Tags: motor, servo, stepper

I want to rotate a gearwheel with a stepper motor. While Arduino is on everything is well.

My gearwheel transfer its power to a gear worm. The worm will go 10th cm and back repeatedly. When I cut the power, Stepper Motor stops where its last step and position. When the power is on Stepper starts from last position but steps starts from the first step.

Assume that 2038 steps are rotating the Motor one revolution. For example, when 1500 step pass and power cut. Worm is on 6th cm now. And the power is on. Stepper is working from 6th cm and is going 2038 steps. Now it is on 16th cm.

If I use servo, when the power is on, I can write the motor to the 0 position. But I have to use stepper motor. How can I fix this?

Stepper Motor: 28 BYJ 48
Driver: ULN2003A

The cod is here;

```
int State;
int Wait;

void setup() {

  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11,OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(8,LOW);
  digitalWrite(9,LOW);
  digitalWrite(10,LOW);
  digitalWrite(11,LOW);
  State = 8;
  Wait = 2; 
}

void loop() {

  turnRight(2038);
  delay(1000);
  turnLeft(2038);
  delay(1000);

  }


void turnRight(int Step) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Step ; i++){
      digitalWrite(State,HIGH);
      delay(Wait);
      digitalWrite(State,LOW);
      IncreaseState();
    }
}

void IncreaseState() {
  State++;
  if (State==12){
    State=8;
  }
}

void turnLeft(int Step) {
for (int i = 0; i < Step ; i++){
      digitalWrite(State,HIGH);
      delay(Wait);
      digitalWrite(State,LOW);
      DecreaseState();
    }

}

void DecreaseState() {
  State--;
  if(State==7){
    State=11;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to to this. The easiest and most commonly used way is to use a limit switch as home position sensor. At startup the device will first drive the motor in the direction of the limit switch, until the switch get's activated. Now the the absolute position on this axis is known and you can go on from there. (CNC machines and 3D printers mostly work that way. Often they retract again from the limit switch and approach the switch again with less speed, to increase the accuracy). For this you just need a micro switch on the axis and connect it to one input pin. In `setup()` you are driving the stepper motor in the direction of the limit switch, until it gets activated. Then you are on position zero and can go on with your sketch.

A more difficult way is to introduce a measurement of position into your device. A servo incorporates a potentiometer connected to the axis. By measuring the voltage on this potentiometer (it is basically a voltage divider), the servos electronics can always know, where it currently is. There are also fader potentiometers, where you don't rotate a knob, but you slide a fader over a linear rail. You might find a fader potentiometer, that fits your scale (10cm is not that much, there might be some).

Or you could save the current position to a non-volatile memory (like EEPROM) and retrieve it, when you start up. But since a power-cut during writing of the position may corrupt the data, you would have to go a more complex way. Something like sensing, that the power was cut, providing the Arduino with power through a big capacitor, so that, when it senses power loss, it still has enough time to write the current position to a non-volatile memory. (This is also better for the EEPROM, than continuously writing to it, since EEPROM has limited write cycles).

All in all I would suggest using the first mentioned method (limit switch). It is used in many devices for a reason. Though it depends on your exact project requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll try limit switch I think.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer chrism didn't mention is to use an "absolute position rotary encoder". It's a device that outputs a bit pattern using "gray code" or "grays binary" that tells you the position of the shaft. The more bits in the encoder, the more precisely you can measure the position. The "gray code" bit pattern enables you to read the changing position without false reading due to contact/sensor bounce.

However, if you want to uniquely detect 2038 separate steps you'd need a 12 bit rotary encoder, which would be a little expensive and take a lot of interface pins.

Comment: Thanks for yor adding. I used Limit Switch and worked well for now. I'll try your idea for improvement in another project.